# Laravel-DomPDF Guzzle GET Request From a CLI

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, guzzle

I want to execute a DomPDF download from the Terminal with a Command. The CLI command executes a API Call with Guzzle. I have made a very simple setup.

Problem

> 500 Server Error

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException]
  Server error: `GET http://localhost:8888/pdf` resulted in a `500 Internal S
  erver Error` response:
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow (truncated...)
```

API Call

> http://localhost:8888/pdf

Command

> php artisan pdf

Project structure

- Commands

  - PDFCommand.php
- Controller

  - PDFController.php
- Views

  - rapport.blade.php

The SourceCode

Route

```
Route::get('pdf', 'PDFController@downloadPDF');
```

PDFCommand.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class PDFCommand extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'pdf';

    protected $description = 'download pdf';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new GuzzleClient;
        $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8888/pdf');

    }
}
```

PDFController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Core;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

class PDFController extends Controller
{

    private $pdf;
    private $client;

    public function downloadPDF()
    {
        $this->pdf = PDF::loadView('report');
        return $this->pdf->download('report.pdf');
    }


}
```

rapport.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Rapport</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>TEST</h1>
                <p>Dit is een test</p>
            </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just read the error? When you receive `500 Server Error`, the response also contains HTML with the error description. It should contain an explanation what's wrong. Just save it to a file (`file_put_contents('...', $response->getBody()->getContents())`) or read in another way.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I just went with another lib, html2pdf. I think the error occurred because methode '$this->pdf->dowload('report.pdf')' needs browser to function. So it has a browser dependacy. I actually got it to work by using Laravel Dusk Unit Test. It opens a browser and does the API Call '/pdf'